# why exception throw excute before thread finished sleep in kotlin(or java)

Tags: java, kotlin, exception

```
    thread(isDaemon = true) {
        var size = 100
        while (size > 0) {
          size--
          println("count $size")
          val t = Thread.currentThread()
          println("$t")
          Thread.sleep(200)
        }
      throw Exception("error cause nothing")
   }.start()
```

i write above code for testing my android app exception caught tool when app crash.
result:

[image]

could somebody can explain the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to start the thread twice. According to the [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html) the `thread` function has a parameter `start` which defaults to `true`, which you're not changing. So the function already calls `start`, which you also do on your last line.

As such, you are calling `start()` twice, which is clearly illegal according to [Thread's Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()):

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.